# Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in plugins/content/rsform/rsform.php on line 57

Tags: php, joomla

I get this error and I don't know how can be fixed this.

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in plugins/content/rsform/rsform.php on line 57
```

and line 57 has this code:

```
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
```

Does anybody know how to fix it ?

Comment: Remove the ampersand after the equals.

Comment: thank youuuu finally after searching for long time